# Read 2D point from a file in C

Tags: c, file, floating-point

I know this has been both answered and asked before, but I can't quite understand the answers given in those posts. I have a .txt file with 2D points stored like this:

```
-1.234,2.345
7.567,-4.567
5.356,-7.456
```

Does someone know how I can read every line and store the first and the second component of every point in two different values. My main difficulty is get line and then split it in two different float variables.

Comment: What are you using to get the line? fgets? fscanf? With fscanf you can read the numbers and convert them directly into double to be stored in variables `fscanf(file, "%lf,%lf", &a, &b);`.

Comment: You are referencing existing questions and answers, but not providing actual links that could then be used to help clarify it for you.

Answer (score 1):

If you are reading the file using `fscanf()`, then simply use

```
fscanf(fp,"%lf,%lf",&firstfloat,&secondfloat);
```

If you are obtaining an entire line as a string, say `str`, then you can use `sscanf()` the same way as `fscanf()`, replacing `fp` with `str`.